# Has age been removed from user profiles?

Tags: support, profile-page

The profile page used to tell us the user's age, except in the case of those users who failed to provide their birth dates. On certain rare occasions this information was of some slight use; namely, when someone asks about a book he read when he was 12, it saves the trouble of asking him when that was.

Has age been removed from the profiles, or is it still there and I'm just not smart enough to find it? If it has been removed, was this done on purpose or by accident?

Comment: [Reported on the master bug list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253460/276025), but no SE response; not sure if it's intentional or not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**It doesn’t appear to be on the site-specific profiles, but it can still be found.**

I’ve checked the new profile page pretty thoroughly, and I can’t find it.

(I know I’ve not done anything to hide my age, and I know hold old I am. If I can’t find that string on the page it’s probably not there.)

But every page has a link to a “network profile”, which covers you for the entire SE network. Notably, it has quite a different design to the site-specific pages.

This page still includes the age. For example, [Jon Skeet’s page](http://stackexchange.com/users/11683/jon-skeet):

[image]

This is still limited based on whether the user is sharing this info with SE, and choosing to share it. Your page doesn’t tell us anything:

[image]

---

I don’t know why it’s been removed – you’d have to ask one of the Stack Exchange designers.

Comment: Ah, so the reason I couldn't find it is that I wasn't smart enough to think of checking the network profile. Thanks!

Comment: Pure speculation: because it's useless piece of fluff that doesn't really do anything except steal screen real estate.

Comment: @DVK Forty-two!